# Normalize numpy ndarray data

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, normalization

My data is numpy ndarray with shape(2,3,4) following this: 
I've try to normalize 0-1 scale for each column through sklearn normalization.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize  

x = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
      [2, 2, 3, 4],
      [3, 2, 3, 4]],
      [[4, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 2, 3, 4],
      [6, 2, 3, 4]]])

x.shape ==> ( 2,3,4) 

x = normalize(x, norm='max', axis=0, )
```

However, I catch the error :

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. the normalize function expected <= 2.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `scikit-learn` expects ndarrays with at most two dims. So, to solve it would be to reshape to `2D`, feed it to `normalize` that gives us a `2D` array, which could be reshaped back to original shape -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize  

normalize(x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1), norm='max', axis=0).reshape(x.shape)
```

Alternatively, it's much simpler with NumPy that works fine with generic ndarrays -

```
x/np.linalg.norm(x, ord=np.inf, axis=0, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! However, the code above does not apply to the column by column, but to the whole data. Which option should be applied?

Comment: @ChrisJoo Not sure what you mean by column to column. Maybe you meant using it along axis=1 instead of axis=0?

Comment: eg. 1st column [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]  should be [  [ 0.1667,  0.3333,  0.5000], 
[ 0.6667 ,  0.8333,  1.0000 ] ] and 2nd column( 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) should be [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ].

Comment: That doesn't look like l2 norm, but a max norm and also along the last axis. So, use : `x/np.linalg.norm(x, ord=np.inf,axis=-1,keepdims=1)` or `norm='max',` with the sklearn version.

Comment: I've solved the problem.. You're a great help to me.. Thank you!!   normalize(x.reshape(x.shape[1],-1), norm='max', axis=0).reshape(x.shape)

Comment: @ChrisJoo Just to be consistent make sure to change `l2` norm to `max` in the question, as it seems that's your expected output. I will update accordingly.